# Просчитать сумму всех span

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть код который берет элемент у которого есть `id="price"` и умножает на данные элемента `id="amount"` и выводит в элемент с `id="summa"`.
Но в данный момент скрипт просчитывает только один элемент с нужным id.
Как взять все элементы с `id="price"` и умножить на все элементы `id="amount"`.
Спасибо

```js
    (function () {
     var price = document.getElementById('price').innerText; 
     var amount = document.getElementById('amount').innerText; 
     var summa = document.getElementById('summa'); 
     var sum = amount*price;
      summa.innerText = sum;
    })();
```

```html
<span id="price">20</span>
<span id="price">30</span>
<span id="amount">2</span>
<span id="amount">4</span><br>
<span id="summa"></span>
```

Comment: не моджет быть одинаковых id

Comment: <span id="amount">2</span>
<span id="amount">4</span><br>

Comment: id смени им и  все пробелмы нет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых id должен быть уникальным, тут нужно использовать class.

```js
(function () {
  var price = document.querySelectorAll('.price'); 
  var amount = document.querySelectorAll('.amount'); 
  var summa = document.getElementById('summa'); 
  var sum = 0;

  price.forEach(function(elem, index){
    sum += elem.textContent * amount[index].textContent;
  });

  summa.innerText = sum;
})();
```

```html
<span class="price">20</span>
<span class="price">30</span>
<span class="amount">2</span>
<span class="amount">4</span><br>
<span id="summa"></span>
```